# Decorator for validating incoming Twilio requests

Tags: python, django, twilio

I've attempted to follow this very straight forward guide on how to prevent non-twilio requests from hitting the webhook url that I've setup for incoming twilio messages. It basically involves copying a function they've developed as a decorator and applying it to the view that handles incoming messages.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-django-project-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden
from functools import wraps
from twilio import twiml
from twilio.request_validator import RequestValidator

import os


def validate_twilio_request(f):
    """Validates that incoming requests genuinely originated from Twilio"""
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create an instance of the RequestValidator class
        validator = RequestValidator(os.environ.get('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'))

        # Validate the request using its URL, POST data,
        # and X-TWILIO-SIGNATURE header
        request_valid = validator.validate(
            request.build_absolute_uri(),
            request.POST,
            request.META.get('HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE', ''))

        # Continue processing the request if it's valid, return a 403 error if
        # it's not
        if request_valid:
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
    return decorated_function
```

Unfortunately, immedialy after I apply the decorator to my view that handles incoming messages, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jason/lib/python3.6/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jason/lib/python3.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/jason/lib/python3.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/jason/webapps/project/jason/jasonsproject/decorators.py", line 14, in decorated_function
    validator = RequestValidator(os.environ.get('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'))
  File "/home/jason/lib/python3.6/twilio/request_validator.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.token = token.encode("utf-8")

Exception Type: AttributeError at /incomingsmsmessages/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `RequestValidator` doesn't accept None.  This should fix it:

```
validator = RequestValidator(os.environ.get('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN', ''))
```